# 405 server error when sending email using php on a static website

Tags: php, email

i have this simple contact form

```
<form action="sokhna-golf-mail.php" method="post" onSubmit="alert('Thank you for submitting your inquiry, a representative will be in contact with you shortly.')">
<input type="hidden" name="source" id="source" value="EINBAY - Sokhna Golf Club">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name *" name="Name" id="Name" required>
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email *" name="Email" id="Email" required>
<textarea spellcheck="true" id="Message" rows="3" cols="20" name="Message" class="fullwidth" placeholder="Enter your message *" style="width:100%" required></textarea>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is the code from `sokhna-golf-mail.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = '6009625383124';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
 var fpw = document.createElement('script');
 fpw.async = true;
 fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
 var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
 })();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"        src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?  id=6009625383124&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>
<?php 
 require_once "Mail.php";

$from     = "mail@einbay.com";
$to       = "user1@sokhnagolfclub.com,user2@einbay.com";
$subject  = " " .$_POST["source"];    
$body  = "Name: ".$_POST["Name"]."\r\n";     
$body .= "Email: ".$_POST["Email"]."\r\n";
$body .= "Message: ".$_POST["Message"]."\r\n";
$body .= "source: ".$_POST["source"]."\r\n";    

$host     = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port     = "465";
$username = "username@gmail.com";
$password = "secret";

$headers = array(
    'From'    => $from,
    'To'      => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host'     => $host,
    'port'     => $port,
    'auth'     => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

$file = 'WestHeightsLeads.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .=  $_POST["Name"].",__,".$_POST["Email"].",__,".$_POST["Subject"].",__,".$_POST["Message"].";__; \n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {

} else {

}

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?msg=xJfDe');
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

when i submit the form i get this error message (405 - http verb used to access this page is not allowed. the page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (http verb) was used to attempt access.)

i searched the web for this issue and found some related topics even here on stackoverflow but none had a valid solution .. but most of the results on google saying this is probably caused by host provider not configured to send smtp mail.

Comment: This is probably related to the settings on your server. To make sure it is unrelated to anything in `sokhna-golf-mail.php`, could you try to remove all PHP and instead just have some tirvial HTML in it?

Comment: i have tried that the page is fine , i even tried to use another mail template [phpMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) still was facing same problem , i read some info about it may be caused by using POST method on static html page but i am not sure yet

Comment: You have a call to `header` after some content (HTML) is already outputted. That will cause errors. Perhaps not the one you are asking about here, but you should fix that anyway.